# Making a "2048 solitaire game" with F#: Creating a fsi file, fs file and fsx file

Tags: f#, 2048

In your solution, you are to represent a board with its pieces as a list of pieces, where each piece
has a color and a position. This is captured by the following type abbreviations:

```
type pos = int * int // A 2-dimensional vector in board - coordinates (not pixels)
type value = Red | Green | Blue | Yellow | Black // piece values
type piece = value * pos //
type state = piece list // the board is a set of randomly organized
pieces
```

In the following, the first coordinate in pos will thought of as a up-down axis also called the row, and
the second as an left-right axis also called the column with (0,0) being the top-left.
Make a library consisting of a signature and an implementation file. The library must contain
the following functions:

```
// convert a 2048 - value v to a canvas color E.g. ,
// > fromValue Green ;;
// val it: color = { r = 0uy
// g = 255 uy
// b = 0uy
// a = 255 uy }
val fromValue: v: value -> Canvas.color

// give the 2048 - value which is the next in order from c, e.g. ,
// > nextColor Blue ;;
// val it: value = Yellow
// > nextColor Black ;;
// val it: value = Black
val nextColor: c: value -> value

// return the list of pieces on a column k on board s, e.g. ,
// > filter 0 [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))];;
// val it: state = [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))]
// > filter 1 [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))];;
// val it: state = []
val filter: k: int -> s: state -> state

// tilt all pieces on the board s to the left ( towards zero on
// the first coordinate ), e.g. ,
// > shiftUp [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (2 , 0)); (Black , (1 ,1))];;
// val it: state = [( Blue , (0 , 0)); (Red , (1 , 0)); (Black , (0 ,))]
val shiftUp: s: state -> state

// flip the board s such that all pieces position change as
// (i,j) -> (2 -i,j), e.g.
// > flipUD [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (2 , 0))];;
// val it: state = [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))]
val flipUD: s: state -> state
// transpose the pieces on the board s such all piece positiosn
// change as (i,j) -> (j,i), e.g. ,
// > transpose [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (2 , 0))];;
// val it: state = [( Blue , (0 , 1)); (Red , (0 , 2))]
val transpose: s: state -> state
// find the list of empty positions on the board s, e.g. ,
// > empty [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (2 , 0))];;
// val it: pos list = [(0 , 0); (0 , 1); (0 , 2); (1 , 1); (1 , 2); (2 , 1); (2 , 2)]
val empty: s: state -> pos list
// randomly place a new piece of color c on an empty position on
// the board s, e.g. ,
// > addRandom Red [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (2 , 0))];;
// val it: state option = Some [( Red , (0 , 2)); (Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (2 , 0))]
val addRandom: c: value -> s: state -> state option
```

**My issue is trying to implement the first function "fromValue" in my fs-file**

I have loaded the Canvas package to the project and ran it through the terminal (dotnet add package DIKU.Canvas) successfully:

```
#r "nuget:diku.canvas, 1.0.1"
```

**This is what I have tried:**

```
module Canvas

type pos = int*int // A 2 - dimensional vector in board - coordinats (not pixels)
type value = Red | Green | Blue | Yellow | Black // piece values
type piece = value*pos //
type state = piece list // the board is a set of randomly organized pieces


let fromValue (v: value) : Canvas.color =
 let Red = Canvas.red
 let Green = Canvas.green
 let Blue = Canvas.blue
 let Yellow = Canvas.yellow
 let Black = Canvas.black
```

Comment: [Pattern matching](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fsharp/fsharp_pattern_matching.htm) can help you here.

Comment: Thanks Brian :) Makes good sense! I wish you a good weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brain says, you could use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) here.

Use this as a starting point:

```ml
let fromValue (v: value) : Canvas.color =
  match v with
  | Red -> Canvas.red
  | Green -> Canvas.green
  | etc ..
```